# How to use scan_csv to read specific csv files in a zip file using polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a zip file that contains thousands of folders and each folder has some files including csvs.

```
- my_zipfile.zip
  - folder_1
    - file_id001.csv
    - file_id002.txt
    - file_id101.csv
    - file_id102.csv
  - folder_2
    - file_id003.csv
    - file_id004.csv
    - file_id103.txt
  ...
```

Currently I extract the zip file manually in the file explorer in Windows than use the code below to read only the csv files that contain "id0" and it works fine.

```
lf = pl.scan_csv("extracted_zip_folder/*/*id0*.csv"
```

Do you know guys how to do the same but without extracting the zip manually ?
I tried to pass the zip file path instead of the extracted one but I got a compute error :

```
lf = pl.scan_csv("my_zipfile.zip/*/*id0*.csv"
```

> ComputeError: no matching files found in my_zipfile.zip/*/*id0*.csv

Comment: Just an aside: If you have control over the data format, you could consider converting the csv to parquet (which is compressed) and getting rid of the zipfile. You can then use `scan_parquet` to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid unzipping the directory by using python's [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module. The globbing patterns won't work out of the box, but we can obtain similar behaviour by combining [`pl.concat`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html) and regex matching.

```py
import re

from zipfile import ZipFile

pl.concat([
    pl.read_csv(ZipFile("my_zip_folder.zip").open(fname).read())
    for fname in ZipFile("my_zip_folder.zip").namelist()
    if re.match(r"my_zip_folder/.*/.*id.*1\.csv", fname)
])
```

**Note.** `pl.read_csv` will read the entire csv file into memory. Perhaps, someone in the comments has an idea on how to make this work also with `pl.scan_csv`.

Comment: `BytesIO` support for `scan_csv` is still an open issue. The most recent advice I found suugested the use of [parquet-fromcsv](https://arrow.apache.org/rust/parquet_fromcsv/index.html) - source: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4950#issuecomment-1594517272

Comment: @jqurious Thanks for the addition. I'll track the issue and update the answer as soon as the feature is implemented.